# how to get the list of products using a category id

Tags: sql, eloquent

I have 2 tables Categories & Products:

```
--------------------------
-       categories       -
--------------------------
- id          | int      -
- name        | varchar  -
- category_id | int      -
--------------------------

--------------------------
-        products        -
--------------------------
- id          | int      -
- name        | varchar  -
- category_id | int      -
--------------------------
```

[image]

[image]

Each category may has a parent category or not, the column category_id refer to it.
Each product belongs to a category.

Exp :
Cat1 -> cate1.2 -> cat1.3->... -> cat1.x-> pro1

Cat2 -> pro2

I want if I search by cat1 or cate1.2 or ... or cat1.x, I can reach the pro1 without knowing all the categories, and the same for pro2??

I use for this sql or eloquent-laravel.

Comment: How you would find cate1.2 is a child of Cat1 from the given table?

Comment: category_id is a foreign key. if it's null the category is parent, if not it's a child of a category.

Comment: It will help to get all parent category id for the given category_id

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Answer (score 0):

Please put these two methods in Category Model.

```
public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}

public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
}
```

and this in Product model

```
public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo( Category::class );
    }
}
```

and get parent category like this.

```
$category = Category::findOrFail(2);
dd( $category->parent );
```

and products of a category like this.

```
dd( $category->products );
```

and category of a product like this.

```
$product = Product::first();

dd( $product->category );
```

Comment: It's not that I want.
I have linked list of categories and one product.
If I search by one of the categories, I reach the product, without knowing all the categories in the list.

Comment: so you want products by category?

Comment: try this. $category->parent->products

Comment: I don't know how many categories in the list.

Comment: but you want a list of products for every category in the list?

Comment: exp : Cat1 -> cate1.2 -> cat1.3->... -> cat1.x-> pro1. If I choose any category I will get the same result => pro1

Comment: can you please share the code how you are implementing it? and category should show multiple products. any category can have more than one product.